# Better database design among two

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, database-design

I have the two different following database designs which achieves the same kind of result what I'm expecting:

Design 1: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4cbe8/2

Design 2: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e7aa/7

But I'm confused on which one is better design. Which database design suits perfect when the size grows in terms of performance for the same sample query that I've it in sqlfiddle?

Comment: Design 2 is more normalized.  The suite name is recorded in one place, and can be changed by changing one row value.

Comment: I'm also +1 for Design 2, but would like to know others' views on it.

Comment: Number two. Much more normalized and easier to expand. You could normalize it even more though by putting the FAILED and PASS status codes into a separate table. This will allow you to add more types of statuses and have descriptions etc linked to them.

Comment: Technically, 2 is NOT more normalized than 1, the functional dependencies in the main fact table are the same (the candidate keys in both cases are id and (suite, run), status is a dependent variable).  Nevertheless, I agree that 2 is a better choice than 1, I would go further and use a surrogate identity for the run as well, and represent the status with {0, 1}.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your valuable suggestions. I'm still going with Design 2 because I feel it is better normalized than the 1 and easier to maintenance as well.